# Do bare infinitives/to infinitives/gerunds refer to both unfinished action and finished action?

Tags: gerunds, to-infinitive, bare-infinitives

Do infinitives and gerunds refer to both unfinished action and finished action?

For example, I started building a house. In this case, “building a house” refers to unfinished action. I finished building a house. In this case, “building a house” indicates finished action.

Comment: Yes - it doesn't matter whether the action being referred to is completed or not.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Also, Action nouns like destruction, restoration it doesn’t  matter whether action is completed or not?

Comment: "The restoration of the building is ongoing" - "The restoration was completed in 2010".